# What does the syntax condition `!` (labelled "except") do?

Tags: rascal

The Rascal grammar contains a production for syntax rules that's not documented:

```
| except: Sym symbol "!" NonterminalLabel
```

It acts syntactically like a follow condition and is in a section commented as "conditional". I see that it's used in the Rascal grammar itself. The `NonterminalLabel` is for individual production rules (not a production with all its alternates). So what does this condition do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ‘E ! add’ occurs in a rule then it simply means E but the rule labeled "add" for E will be as-if not existing.
This restriction goes only one level deep, so recursive E's will have the "add" rule again.

For example:

```
syntax E 
  = id: Id
  | app: E "(" {E!comma ","}* ")"
  > left mul: E "*" E
  > left add: E "+" E
  > right comma: E "," E
  ;
```

The `E` in `{E ","}*` of the function application rule is restricted to not be the comma expression, in order to avoid syntactic ambiguity.

- The benefit here is that you do not have to introduce yet another non-terminal which also logically represents expressions.
- The pitfall is that the ! operator is a hard restriction and thus may make the accepted language actually smaller: use of ! may lead to unexpected parse errors if not used carefully.

Side note: The ! operator is the primitive constraint type used to model the  priority (>) and associative (left, right) semantics as well, but those are transitive and checked for safety, etc. This on the other hand is a brutal removal of a definition and thus may change the accepted sentences of your language.